# How to populate selectOneMenu list with values from 1 to 31

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I need to create a selectOneMenu list for the day of birth. I need something like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<32;i++)
system.out.println(i);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why haven't you been through a JSF book/tutorial first? I recommend to do so before continuing with JSF.

Comment: You've got prebuilt calendar components for that.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to use [`f:selectItems`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnask/index.html). There is also a [good wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info) at StackOverflow.

And by the way, to select a date, you could use a [date picker](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/calendarHome.jsf) of a rich component library like PrimeFaces or RichFaces.

Comment: Or if OP doesn't want to add a datepicker from one of those libraries, he/she could use a `<h:inputText>` and decorate it with a jQuery component, but the datepicket component would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is creating a list in the backing bean with the values and return them in view using selectIems. For example:

```
@ManagedBean
public class ManagedBean{
    private ArrayList list;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        for(int i=1; i<32;i++)
            list.add(i);
    }

    //getter and setter
}
```

in the view:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{managedBean.someValue}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{managedBean.list}" var="day" itemValue="#{day}" itemLabel=#{day}/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without backing bean:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{...}"  >              
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="31">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{i}" itemValue="#{i}" />       
    </c:forEach>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```